# Why does my IsWin function only work for the opponent player in my multiplayer game?

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I have created a multiplayer online TIC-TAC-TOE game with HTML, CSS, Javascript and for server side I used Flask.

All game logic  works on the client side, but I am stuck at the `IsWin` function which only works for the opponent Player not for the winning Player. I don't understand why it words like this.

I want this function to work for all Players

```js
static isWin() {
  let win = true
  console.log(this.currentPlayer.name + this.currentPlayer.moves)
  for (let i in this.winMoves) {
    win = true;
    if (this.currentPlayer == this.itself) {
      console.log(this.winMoves[i])
    }
    for (let j in this.winMoves[i]) {
      if (this.currentPlayer == this.itself) {
        console.log(this.winMoves[i][j])
      }
      if (!(this.currentPlayer.moves.includes(this.winMoves[i][j]))) {
        win = false;
        break;
      }
    }


    if (win) {
      console.log("win")
      this.isFinish = true
      document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += document.getElementById("reset-game").innerHTML
      return true
    }
  }
  if (!win) {
    if (this.player1.moves.length + this.player2.moves.length === 9) {
      alert(" match draw ")
      return true
    }
  }
  //this.isRunning = false
  return false
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.